# ORA-01001 with text command type

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have very strange problem with some C# code.
I have method like this:

```
public static void LoadDataToList(string viewName, ListBox lbxToLoad)
{
    try
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = DBConnection.EnsureConnectionToDB();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + viewName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<CustomTypes.ListBoxItems> listItems = new List<CustomTypes.ListBoxItems>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var itemValue = dr.GetOracleValue(0);
            var itemText = dr.GetOracleValue(1);
            listItems.Add(new CustomTypes.ListBoxItems() { Value = itemValue, Text = itemText });
        }

        lbxToLoad.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
        lbxToLoad.ItemsSource = listItems;
        lbxToLoad.IsEnabled = true;

        dr.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        MsgHandling(3);
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I run it in `while (dr.Read())` I got error ORA-01001. But as you see I don't use procedure command type... It is simple select query from view. In view is no cursor. Any Idea what is going on?

**EDIT:**

VIEW SQL

```
select distinct
      ti.value as id
    , ti.value as value
from
    x.table1 t
  , x.table2 ti
WHERE
    t.t1_num= ti.t2_num AND ti.type_id = 20003
ORDER by
    ti.value asc;
```

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` is useless because you don't use any parameters at all.

Comment: I know, but I try to do everything, and still got this error...

Comment: `CommandType.Text` should be default. Can you post view definition?

Comment: It's very likely that the `OracleDataReader` object is using a cursor under the hood; that is the typical way to retrieve rows one at a time. And this error can also happen if you have too many cursors open at once: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01001_invalid_cursor.htm

Comment: Is your connection opened? Try to open it before you create reader `cmd.Connection.Open()`

Comment: It should be. But when connection is closed, we will get error like this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember I had some strange problems myself and it was due to closed connection :)

Comment: I would not think you would get an error like that if the connection were closed. Hard to see how one could get an Oracle error if one weren't even connected to the Oracle DB :-)